# How to access text in this JSON using JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON output and I want to extract text in this out, how can I extract using PHP?

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: no it is not duplicate

Comment: So you can't use the answer from this to extract it? `$obj2 = json_decode( $json, true );`

Comment: how can i use can you please help me

Comment: That's _definitely_ a duplicate. If you do not think it is, you'll need to explain why.

Comment: @halfer ok fine if its duplicate so could you give me the answer of my question using duplicate question if you can so i will appreciate you

Comment: How about you give it a go? Please edit into your question _an attempt_ using the several answers on the proposed duplicate. Put the JSON into a string variable, and then see what `print_r(json_decode($json, true))` gives you? **Trying things** is the best way to learn.

Comment: $res = json_decode($result, true);

foreach ( $res['rows'][0]['elements'] as  $row )
{   
  echo "Distance :". $row['distance']['text'];
}

Comment: this was the solution

Comment: Aside: please do not criticise folks for amending grammatical/spelling/readability errors in posts. That is a very useful service, and it is undertaken entirely by volunteers. Be happy that your post was improved `:-)`